# Unable to install_local() with R Shiny Golem app

Tags: r, github, shiny, golem

I am creating a Shiny app using the golem framework. I am at the last part where I am testing to see whether the app can be installed like a package by running  `remotes::install_local()`.

However, I am running into the following error:

```
remotes::install_local()
Error: Failed to install 'XXXX' from local:
  HTTP error 404.
  Not Found

  Did you spell the repo owner (`XXXX`) and repo name (`XXXX`) correctly?
  - If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.
```

Here are the files that are in the project folder - I think that the structure is correct?:

[image]

I'm a bit confused, if I am trying to install locally, why is it requiring the repo owner and name? (It's also listing the incorrect repo too).

Thanks

Comment: What does your DESCRIPTION file look like? Where is the `XXXX` name coming from? Do you reference your own package as a dependency in the DESCRIPTION file?

Comment: Posit Community [crosspost](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-install-local-with-r-shiny-golem-app/159373).

Comment: The question and suggested solution are misleading. There is no context at all around the answer or further explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to assign a personal access token using `credentials::set_github_pat()` before running `install_github('owner/repo')`.